# Make Multi-Line Plain Text field Searchable from AllItems Page

Tags: search, search-results, managed-property, crawl, search-schema

Requirement: Make multi-line plain text field searchable from AllItems page.

What I've done so far: Created new site-level column, "Notes", added it to my list, created a new managed property, "NotesProperty", and configured the below settings to be searchable, queryable, and retrievable (https://mstechtalk.com/create-multiline-text-field-searchable/).

However, it's been several hours but when I try testing it out it's still not working. Am I missing something obvious??

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use SharePoint 2013 and we had it a few times that this did not work either. In our case **resetting the index and performing a fresh full crawl** solved our issue.

In case you try this and resetting the index throws an error you might want to take a look at this: **[Index reset throwing exception](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247248/index-reset-throwing-exception/247250#247250)**

Comment: This is spot on. I went to List Settings > Advanced settings > and clicked "Reindex List". Then, had one of our admins kick-off a full-crawl. It took about a full day to start seeing search results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experience this very often, sometimes it takes anywhere from 1-24 hours for the managed properties to index and get crawled. Since in SharePoint Online you do not have a way to kick off the timer job. You may just need to wait up to 24 hours. It does appear that you have everything configured correctly though!

Crappy, but unfortunately this is how it is now. Keep us posted

Comment: Yep, turns out I might be a little impatient : ) Re-indexing the list and performing a full crawl did the trick. It took about a day to see the results. Thanks for the note.